# A surjective morphism of affine curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,U$ be smooth affine geometrically integral curves such that $g(X) \geq 1$ and $U$ is dense open in $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, where $k$ denotes a number field. Suppose we have a surjective morphism $\varphi: X \rightarrow U$, of degree 3 (if it helps).

Are the following maps surjective?

1. $X(k) \rightarrow U(k)$
2. $X(\mathbb{A}_k) \rightarrow U(\mathbb{A}_k)$

For the first one, it seems to be true since $\varphi$ maps $k$-points to $k$-points and since it is surjective, every $k$-point of $U$ must be hit by some $k$-point of $X$.

For the second one, the only fact I have is from this [note](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/adelictop.pdf) by Conrad, see Theorem 4.5. Even then, I'm not sure the fibres are geometrically integral, and even if so, the best I can get is that this induced map on adeles is open.

Comment: 1. No, take the projection of $V(y^2=x^3+6)\subset\Bbb A^2_{\Bbb Q}$ on to the $y$-axis. The former has no $\Bbb Q$-points, is an open subset of an elliptic curve, and the map is finite + dominant = surjective. 2. If these are adelic points (are these adelic points?), I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: @KReiser By your example, 2 should be false since the rational points can be embedded (diagonally) into the adelic points.